# Comment help always expanded in Incognito mode in chrome

Tags: support, comments

Just in incognito mode, the comment help is always starts expanded. I can collapse it but if there are 10 answers in a page, it's expanded for all 10 of them. Anyone else notice that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design; new users need help with comments.

We suppress the help (you can still show it by explicitly clicking show help) once you reach a certain reputation threshold.

In fact, there are dozens of behaviors on the site specific to new and low rep users, not just this one...

Comment: I think you missed this part: "if there are 10 answers in a page, it's expanded for all 10 of them." That might be by design, but it's also kind of annoying.

Comment: @joel think about it: this would only be true in a very rare and limited set of circumstances. You would have to be a brand new user, who owns (has just asked) a question with 10+ answers, and you are *viewing the question you own*. That is the *only* scenario where all comments are *pre-expanded*.